# Fragment Animation in when popBackStackImmediate() method used

Tags: android, fragment

How to load animation when backstack fragment or removing fragment in stack?

I am using below code for remove fragment but i don't know how to add **setCustomAnimation** method to Load animation.
//Remove fragment in stack

```
private boolean returnBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager fm) {
    List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
    if (fragments != null && fragments.size() > 0) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                if (fragment.getChildFragmentManager()
                        .popBackStackImmediate()) {
                    Log.d("tag", "CalledInside");

                    return true;
                } else {

                    return returnBackStackImmediate(fragment
                            .getChildFragmentManager());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "how to load animation" ? typically you do it by  AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator() / AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()

Comment: I am creating Actionbar activitiy with nested fragment working properly but i don't know how to add animation when back pressed